# Is it possible to make somehow multi volume RAR archives by reading data from named pipe or standard input?

Tags: linux, zip, archiving, rar

I usually RAR my files into 200MB parts on my VPS, and free space is always scarce. Would be nice to make the multi volume part1.rar, part2.rar etc. archives from a named pipe, which could be fed even with cURL or ffmpeg (in case of a video), and RAR archiver would take the input data from the named pipe (so called FIFO, Linux command mkfifo). Unfortunately currently RAR has no explicit support for FIFO-s, unlike ZIP (at least info-zip) which has an -FI option. RAR can only read data from STDIN, but in this case I always get a single volume archive, which is too big for me. Is there a way to make the multi volume archives without downloading the whole file?

Comment: `7zip` has command line switches to read from stdin, and to create multi volume archives.  It might be an alternative.  I suspect you could probably use `tar` too, as it can do multiple volume archives too.  Can't try them out for you though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i do it from Windows (rar.exe) the linux port should be the same:

dir \temp /s|"\Program Files\WinRAR"\rar a -siInsidefile.txt -v1024b -ag_MMMDDYYYY-HHMM archive

this gives me :
archive_May312016-0945.part1.rar
archive_May312016-0945.part2.rar
archive_May312016-0945.part3 ... etc

wich contains:
insidefile.txt

of 1024 bytes each

with the text file holding the contents of the redirection of my dir command.

Comment: Thx, now it works, it turned out that I had to update my rar installation from 5.3 to 5.4 beta 2